# What could cause content to revert on a page refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails application and have included some custom jquery.

I have one `div` nested within another `div`.

The nested `div` contains text and it has a `height` of `100px`.

I want the nested `div` to be positioned at the very bottom of the container `div`.

I achieved that by using:

```
position: absolute;

bottom: 0;
```

In my `custom.css.scss`. This solution worked great.

HOWEVER!

The issue I am having is that when I refresh the page in my browser, my nested `div` that I want positioned at the bottom of the container `div` is reverted back to it's previous position.

Does anyone know, why this could be happening?

Below I have listed the code for my `div`. The container and nested.

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nested">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        </div><!-- end div .nested -->
    </div><!-- end div .wrapper -->
</a><!-- end anchor tag -->
```

CSS

```
    .container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 250px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FAAA2C;
    }

    .nested {
    background-color: #FFFFF2;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position:relative to the .container class. This should fix it. JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cw6dotja/

```css
.container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 250px;
    border-top: 5px solid #FAAA2C;
    position:relative;
    }

    .nested {
    background-color: #FFFFF2;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nested">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        </div><!-- end div .nested -->
    </div><!-- end div .wrapper -->
</a><!-- end anchor tag -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that solution already. It does not work however.

Answer (score 0):

HA! SO I HAD TO RUN THESE COMMANDS AND IT SOLVED MY ISSUES!

```
rake assets:clobber

rake assets:precompile
```

I finally solved this issues, I have been having forever.